# What is the final confirmed status of those characters?

Tags: fables-comics

Death in the "Fables" series is often cheap and many important characters come back after being killed in one way or the other: Snow survived a headshot, Bigby will apparently "die seven times", Totenkinder had backup spells pulling her back from the dead (and she died many, many times in multiple stories).

Towards the end of the "Fables" main comic series, many main characters are apparently killed - probably for real this time:

> Beast and Ozma have been killed by mind-controlled Bigby. Cinderella forces Totenkinder/Bellflower to use the final spell, which killed both of them.

Since there were quite a few spin-offs from the main series, has any of those characters mentioned above returned after the events from the "Fables: Happily Ever After"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this point, it appears as though the characters

> Beast and Ozma

are permanently dead.

> Beast had passed on his curse to his daughter, Bliss.  So both he and Ozma would be reliant on the "belief of the mundanes" to recreate them - but Bellflower's final spell probably prevents that from happening.

There was nothing in the Everafter series to indicate otherwise.